# CSV Import issues in R

Tags: r, csv, dataset

After importing a csv file, R separated my data into columns every comma it reads.
My issue is that i had originally **two columns** where i had different values  that are **floating numbers**, and the other column is the **sum of all of these floating number**. So R spread these elements in 5 or 6 columns sometimes less columns, sometimes more, depending on the number of commas existing.

There's a facilitation in this issue: the **first column is delimited from parenthesis**: so for example the first row first column is (-5,5+9)+(-10+12) and the second column would be the sum of this floating numbers. So i can easily see where the first column stops, after the **second column** (that is the sum of the elements of the first column) there are **at least 2 or more empty columns** so that i can easily recognize where the second column ends. Now what i have to do is to rearrange my dataset in the original form. I post the structure of the dataset for an easy understanding

[image]

here's is the code of the first rows

```
   Y= structure(list(V24 = structure(c(66L, 15L, 44L, 28L, 68L, 10L
    ), .Label = c("", "(-0", "(-0+7", "(-1", "(-1+11", "(-1+11)+(-13", 
    "(-1+11)+(-18+18", "(-1+3)+(-10+14)", "(-1+8)", "(-2", "(-2+10", 
    "(-2+10)", "(-2+10)+(-13", "(-2+11", "(-2+11)", "(-2+11)+(-13", 
    "(-2+11)+(-14+17)", "(-2+12", "(-2+12)", "(-2+12)+(-14", "(-2+12)+(-14+15", 
    "(-2+12)+(-14+16)", "(-2+6)+(-8+10)+(-14", "(-2+7", "(-2+7)", 
    "(-2+7)+(-11", "(-2+7)+(-13", "(-2+8", "(-2+8)+(-10", "(-2+8)+(-11", 
    "(-2+8)+(-13", "(-2+8)+(-15", "(-2+9", "(-2+9)", "(-2+9)+(-13", 
    "(-2+9)+(-14", "(-3", "(-3+10", "(-3+10)", "(-3+10)+(-13", "(-3+10)+(-13+14", 
    "(-3+10)+(-14+14", "(-3+11", "(-3+11)", "(-3+11)+(-13", "(-3+12", 
    "(-3+12)", "(-3+12)+(-13", "(-3+13)", "(-3+7", "(-3+8", "(-3+8)", 
    "(-3+8)+(-11+12", "(-3+9", "(-3+9)", "(-4", "(-4+10", "(-4+10)", 
    "(-4+10)+(-11+12)", "(-4+11", "(-4+11)", "(-4+12", "(-4+12)", 
    "(-4+13)", "(-4+14)", "(-4+6)+(-9", "(-4+8", "(-4+8)+(-10+14)", 
    "(-4+9", "(-4+9)+(-10+11)+(-13", "(-4+9)+(-12+13)+(-18+18", "(-4+9)+(-13+14", 
    "(-4+9)+(-14+15)", "(-4+9)+(-9", "(-5", "(-5+10", "(-5+10)", 
    "(-5+10)+(-13", "(-5+11)", "(-5+12)", "(-5+13)+(-14", "(-6", 
    "(1+6)+(-8+9", "S"), class = "factor"), V25 = structure(c(7L, 
    67L, 66L, 58L, 66L, 54L), .Label = c("", "(-4+11", "(-5", "10", 
    "12", "25)+(-14+15)", "25+12", "25+14", "3)", "3+6)", "3+7", 
    "5", "5)", "5)+(-10", "5)+(-11", "5)+(-11+13)+(-14", "5)+(-13", 
    "5)+(-13+13", "5)+(-13+14", "5)+(-14", "5)+(-16", "5)+(-16+16", 
    "5)+(-16+17)+(-21+22", "5)+(-17", "5)+(-18+18", "5+10", "5+10)", 
    "5+10)+(-13", "5+11", "5+11)", "5+11)+(-13", "5+11)+(-17+17", 
    "5+11)+(-21+21", "5+12", "5+12)", "5+12)+(-13", "5+12)+(-20+20", 
    "5+13", "5+13-13", "5+14", "5+15", "5+16", "5+16)", "5+18)", 
    "5+6)+(-14+14", "5+7", "5+7)+(-13", "5+7)+(-15", "5+7)+(-9+12", 
    "5+8", "5+8)", "5+8)+(-17", "5+9", "5+9)", "5+9)+(-13", "5+9)+(-14", 
    "5+9)+(-22", "50)", "50+10)+(-14", "50+14", "50+7", "6", "7", 
    "75)", "75)+(-14+15", "8", "9", "T"), class = "factor"), V26 = structure(c(31L, 
    1L, 1L, 29L, 1L, 29L), .Label = c("", "10", "11", "25)", "25)+(-14+15", 
    "25+15", "4", "5", "5)", "5)+(-13", "5)+(-14", "5)+(-16", "5)+(-16+17)", 
    "5)+(-20+21)", "5+10)+(-13", "5+13", "5+14", "5+14)", "5+14)+(-18+18", 
    "5+15", "5+15)", "5+16)", "5+17", "5+18", "5+18)", "5+23", "50)", 
    "50+16", "6", "7", "75)", "75+14", "75+15", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), 
        V27 = structure(c(9L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 9L), .Label = c("", 
        "10", "11", "12", "25", "25)", "25+17", "3", "5", "5)", "5+14", 
        "5+15)", "5+15)+(-18", "50)", "6", "7", "75", "75)", "8", 
        "9"), class = "factor"), V28 = structure(c(9L, 12L, 15L, 
        1L, 8L, 1L), .Label = c("", "1", "10", "11", "2", "25)", 
        "3", "4", "5", "5)", "5+19", "6", "7", "75", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), 
        V29 = structure(c(1L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
        "25", "2prol", "30", "40", "41", "5", "5)", "50", "52", "75", 
        "8", "9"), class = "factor"), V30 = structure(c(1L, 6L, 12L, 
        5L, 7L, 13L), .Label = c("", "25", "3", "3conc", "4", "45", 
        "46", "5", "52", "56", "6", "60", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), 
        V31 = structure(c(15L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 7L), .Label = c("", 
        "35", "40", "43", "4mot", "5", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", 
        "57", "60", "63", "7"), class = "factor"), V32 = c(43L, NA, 
        NA, 52L, NA, 57L), V33 = c(45L, NA, NA, 59L, NA, 56L), V34 = c(55L, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = 3:8, class = "data.frame")
```

So my idea is:

1. read all the columns, identify and separate the *first* from the *second column*: the last element of the first column is highlighted by the closing parenthesis
2. Working on the **first one**: i would say "take the value of the next column and add to the previous column adding a comma before"
3. Working on the **second one**: Since the second column starts where there's the first element after the closing parenthesis, i would take the first value (in that case we have an integer) or if the following column has a number (so that the column is not empty) add the number of the following column to the first columns linked by a comma.

Note: i have the idea how to do it, but i can't translate these ideas into a code, how can i do this?

Comment: I may take a step back and try to import the csv correctly if you want to get it back to the original form. Have you tried specifying the columns are characters? In base, it would be something like `read.table("csv_filepath.csv", colClasses = c("character", "character", "numeric"))`

Comment: it seems that the commas of the decimal numbers are being read as column delimiter. The `read.csv()` function uses comma as delimiter, so the string `(-5,5+9)+(-10+12)` is being read as `col1 = (-5` and `col2 = 5+9)+(-10+12)`. Perhaps it is better to reread the table, defining a specific delimiter ( i.e a whitespace) or modify your decimal character to a period (dot)